# Javascript - IE8 Ignoring Condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop, continue

My question:

Why is this condition being ignored in IE 8?

```
if (dynCheck[0].innerHTML == 'Empty' || dynCheck[0].innerHTML == "")` {continue}
```

More details:

I have a loop that is storing an array of list items into another array. I have a condition that checks if the first list item has a value of "Empty" if it does then `continue`. For some reason IE8 is ignoring this condition. Could it be because I'm checking against an Array holding a value?

Here is the entire loop:

```
for(var dynEl = 1; dynEl <= dynLists; dynEl++) {

        //Get Array of List Items
        var dynCheck = document.getElementById('loc' + dynEl).getElementsByTagName('li');

        //Check if it is empty or not
        if (dynCheck[0].innerHTML == 'Empty' || dynCheck[0].innerHTML == "") {continue}

        //If there is content then add it to the Array
        dynElArr[dynElIndx] = dynCheck;

        //Increment Index
        dynElIndx++;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you debug it with a console line to see what is in it? Could be a whitespace character.

Comment: Don't we all just love Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is not necessarily the same between browsers, especially in regards to whitespace *between* nodes.

Case 1:

```
<ul><li>Item</li></ul>
```

Case 2:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

May give different results.

Try `.nodeValue` or select the actual textnode first and use `.textContent`/`.nodevalue`